# Difference between __weak UIDataType *weakSelf and UIDataType __weak *weakSelf?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm seeing two different implementations...

```
__weak UIDataType *weakSelf = self;
```

and

```
UIDataType __weak *weakSelf = self;
```

Yet they both seems to work. Is there a difference in terms of what happens under the hood?

Thanks in advance for your wisdom!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference. Since `__weak` can only apply to pointer-to-object types, the compiler recognizes that there is only one meaning that makes sense for all of the following:

```
__weak UIDataType *weakSelf;
UIDataType __weak *weakSelf;
UIDataType * __weak weakSelf;
```

The same applies to the other ownership qualifiers (`__strong`, `__autoreleasing`, etc.)

If you're comfortable reading technical specifications of programming languages, you can read more about it here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#spelling.

Comment: Thanks for this - also for linking the relevant reference.